# Why does Java show a worse result when using the same Processing code?

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I have written the exact same code twice, once in the Processing (4.3) IDE and once in Eclipse using the core.jar file. In both IDEs the code results in a rectangle with rounded corners on a white background. But the quality of the rectangle is way worse using eclipse and the window is also bigger despite using the same window size.
(Windows version: 10.0.19045 Build 19045)
(Eclipse version: 2023-03 (4.27.0))

Code in Processing (4.3) IDE

```
final static int screen_width = 1400;
final static int screen_height = 600;
final static int button_width = 500;
final static int button_height = 200;
final static int border_width = 8;

PVector button_startingpoint;


public void settings() {
  size(screen_width, screen_height);
}

public void setup() {
  frameRate(60);
  button_startingpoint = new PVector((screen_width / 2) - (button_width / 2), (screen_height / 2) - (button_height / 2));
}

public void draw() {
  background(255);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  strokeWeight(border_width);
  rect(button_startingpoint.x, button_startingpoint.y, button_width, button_height, 24);
}
```

Code in Eclipse

```
package main;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PVector;

public class Startup extends PApplet {
    final static int screen_width = 1400;
    final static int screen_height = 600;
    final static int button_width = 500;
    final static int button_height = 200;
    final static int border_width = 8;

    PVector button_startingpoint;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main("main.Startup");
    }

    public void settings() {
        size(screen_width, screen_height);
    }

    public void setup() {
        frameRate(60);
        button_startingpoint = new PVector((screen_width / 2) - (button_width / 2), (screen_height / 2) - (button_height / 2));
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(255);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        strokeWeight(border_width);
        rect(button_startingpoint.x, button_startingpoint.y, button_width, button_height, 24);
    }

}
```

Result in Processing (4.3) IDE:

[image: Result in Processing (4.3) IDE]

Result in Eclipse:

[image: Result in Eclipse]

Comment: Interesting. Might be a Windows specific issue (can't replicate it on OSX). Just to weed out a few options for others it would be great if you could update your question to include the version of Windows and eclipse you're using. The other things I'd check are if the JDK used is the same (through I doubt that's the issue) and double checking what commands eclipse uses to run.(Or even trying to export/launch your eclipse PApplet from `cmd` directly to check if there's a difference (to exclude the chance of a silly OS related display/zoom/option on the same screen interfering for any reason).HTH

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Versions are now included! JDK is indeed the same and I just ran the PApplet from cmd, still the worse quality and slightly bigger window size than specified.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I don't have access to Windows 10 easily at the moment, but hopefully someone in the community does. It's interesting that running from `cmd` produces yet another result (bigger window). I'd also try to explicitly set the renderer in an attempt to isolate the bug (e.g. `size(screen_width, screen_height, JAVA2D);` (should be default) or `size(screen_width, screen_height, P2D);` to check if the behaviour is different)